# $\pi$-complement of direct product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G = N_1 \times N_2 \times \ldots \times N_n$ be a finite group and the direct product of the normal subgroups $N_i$. Let $\pi$ be a set of primes, then a $\pi$-complement is a subgroup $K$ such that $|K|$ is only divisible by primes not in $\pi$ and the index of $K$ in $G$ is only divisible by primes from $\pi$.

Now if $K$ is a $\pi$-complement of $G$, then
$$
 K = K_1 \times K_2 \times \cdots \times K_n
$$
with $\pi$-complement $K_i$ of $N_i$, and vice versa if $K_i$ are $\pi$-complements of $N_i$, then $K = K_1 \times K_2 \times \cdots \times K_n$ is a $\pi$-complement of $G$.

Does the above result holds? I nowhere found this result, so I am unsure, also how would you going to prove it?

I have a proof of the following related result: If $G = N_1 \times N_2 \times \ldots \times N_n$ is a finite group and the direct product of the normal subgroups $N_i$, then every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ has the form
$$
 S_1 \times S_2 \times \ldots \times S_n
$$
for $S_i \in \mbox{Syl}_p(N_i)$ and vice versa for $S_i \in \mbox{Syl}_p(N_i)$ we have $S := S_1 S_2 \cdots S_n = S_1 \times S_2 \times \ldots \times S_n$ and $S \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$.

Comment: But $|L \times L \times \cdots \times L| = |L|^n \ne n|L|$???

Comment: Isn't it obvious just from their orders that if $K_i$ is a $\pi$-complement of $N_i$ then $K_1 \times \cdots \times K_n$ is a $\pi$-complement of $N$? For the other direction, just use the more general result that if $K$ is a $\pi$-complement of $G$ and $N \unlhd G$, then $N \cap K$ is a $\pi$-complement of $N$.

Comment: That $K := K_1 \times K_2 \times \cdots \times K_n$ is a $\pi'$-group is obvious, but that $|G : K|$ has just prime divisors from $\pi$ is obvious too?

Comment: Really $|G : A \times B| = |G : A||G : B|$? I can only get $|G : A| = |G : A\times B||A\times B : A| = |G : A\times B||B|$, hence $|G : A \times B| = |G : A| / |B|$, but that would contradict, as in general $|G : B| \ne 1 / |B|$??

Comment: Sorry I meant $|G:K|$ is the product of the $|N_i:K_i|$.

Comment: @Stefan sorry about my pure nonsense earlier.